# Html.Raw working not working with inline-css

Tags: html, css

I have a web app, where customers can create events and give them some text for describing purposes. This text can be formatted, which is achieved by creating html-tags and inline css in the background. The user does not see that.

The view rendering this texts has:

```
@Html.Raw(describingtext)
```

The problem I am facing is, that this inline css leads to problems rendering the entire page: elements are displaced all over the visible space.

Is there any way of handling this generated inline css?

Comment: What is content of the `describingtext` variable?

Comment: Something like <h2 style="text-align: center;">Headline</h2>. Without style="..." it works fine, but Html.Raw can not handle that inline css and produces things like <h2>style="..."</p>

Comment: Please, add [mcve] to clarify your question.

Comment: I think, the reason is double quotes is not escaped. But I don't want to guess. I need to see verifiable code snippet.